# What's the difference between `use my_db` and `my_db.my_table` in mysql?

Tags: mysql

We have lots of database in one instance.

Our query language is:

```
use db1; select * from table1;
use db2; select * from table2;
```

But when we change to this style, the MySQL server CPU load dropped a lot:

```
select * from db1.table1;
select * from db2.table2;
```

What's the different between them?

Which one should we use?

Comment: honestly I do not think it's related. And there should not be any difference

Comment: @AlexandrKapustin We also think there should n't be any difference. Maybe we should test it by pure code without any framework.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can work with multiple databases in a single query. Each table belongs to a single database. Its full name is: `database.table`.

- If you are sticking to a single database, then you probably don’t want to work with the database prefix. `USE database` allows you to dispense with the prefix.
- If you are using multiple databases simultaneously, then you’re never going to be in the right database. At the very lease, you will need to prefix the *other* database tables.

I don’t know how much work MySQL does when you apply the `USE database` statement, but I imagine that it’s not very important in the overall scheme of things. Under normal circumstances you are working with a single database so issuing the `USE` statement once should be the end of it.

Certainly if you’re constantly switching between the two, and especially if you’re joining tables from different databases, then you should prefix the tables.